# Python- how to get list of self variables in a class consist of N-self

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, self, mesa

Edited:

I want to generate N-number of agents. Each agent will have a name, so I create a random name from names and assigned it to class Agent.

After I run the model, I want to get the list of my agents name.

This is from mesa:

```
import names
from mesa import Agent, Model
from mesa.time import RandomActivation

class Agent(Agent):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name= names.get_full_name()
        self.wealth = 1

    def step(self):
        pass

class Model(Model):
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.num_agents = N
        self.schedule = RandomActivation(self)

        for i in range(N):
            a = MoneyAgent(i)
            self.schedule.add(a)

    def step(self):
        self.schedule.step()
```

on interactive session

```
gow = MoneyModel(10)
gow.step()
atr = list([a for a in MoneyAgent.name])
print(atr)
```

I got this error:

*File "C:\src__init__.py", line 7, in 
    atr = list([a for a in MoneyAgent.name])
AttributeError: type object 'MoneyAgent' has no attribute 'name'*

How to fix it?

Comment: your first line in the `__init__` method has a syntax error. You are calling `names.get_full_name()`. However, the variable you are passing to the method is _name_, not _names_

Comment: When I use _names_, I'll get this error : _'int' object has no attribute 'get_full_name'_

Comment: he is importing `names` above.

Comment: This is really really unclear. What does "N-self" mean? Why do you think the class MoneyAgent should have a `name` attribute? What output are you hoping to get?

Comment: why is `name` a number? isn't that supposes to be a name?

Comment: @DoronCohen that's right, the post was edited and didn't see the import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my interpretation of your problem:  You're creating a `MoneyModel` object which contains a collection of `MoneyAgent` objects stored in a collection-like object referred to as `MoneyModel.schedule`, and you want a `list` of the `name`s of each `MoneyAgent` object within your `MoneyModel.schedule` collection.

Assuming `MoneyModel.schedule` behaves as an iterable object, the following should work:

```
atr = [agent.name for agent in gow.schedule]
```